# wix toolset build tools not getting installed

Tags: wix

wix 3.11 RC-2 exe not getting installed. not giving any errors just completes without any display.

Anyone knows how to use wix binaries or make exe working in my project since it is giving be error "
wix toolset build tools v3 not installed"

Comment: The exact error I'm seeing is "The WiX Toolset v3 build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" - is this the same error you're getting? I get the same error for v4 too. I have the "WiX Toolset v3.11.0.1507" installed and listed in Programs and Features.

Comment: Look for logs in %TEMP% directory.

Comment: Got it resolved by running wix3.8 exe as Run as Administrator

Comment: I had to log in as Administrator, running as Administrator from a session using a different account did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with VS2015 and WiX toolset 3.10 when using a bootstrapper project template. My workaround was changing the wixproj: remove the condition from

```
<Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition=" '$(WixTargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
<Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3 build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" /> 
</Target>
```

I found the `$(WixTargetsImported)` is nowhere defined so no surprise it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I accidentally installed the [WiX.Toolset](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WiX.Toolset/) from nuget. This version is outdated and not maintained. It misses the following line from `wix.targets` hence the error.

```xml
<WixTargetsImported>true</WixTargetsImported>
```

Once I went to [WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork) all went well.

Comment: Where in the .wixproj should one add this line?